# Nativescript unable to get values of Textfield element using angular 6

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

NativeScript version 4.2.4
Angular version 6.0

I have two TextFields in my login page

```
<StackLayout class="input-field">
  <TextField class="input" hint="Username" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" [(ngModel)]="user.userName" returnKeyType="next" (returnPress)="focusPassword()"></TextField>
  <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout class="input-field">
  <TextField #password class="input" hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password" [returnKeyType]="isLoggingIn ? 'done' : 'next'" (returnPress)="focusConfirmPassword()"></TextField>
  <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout *ngIf="!isLoggingIn" class="input-field">
  <TextField #confirmPassword class="input" hint="Confirm password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.confirmPassword" returnKeyType="done"></TextField>
  <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
</StackLayout>

<Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Log In' : 'Sign Up'" (tap)="submit()" class="btn btn-primary m-t-20"></Button>
```

All I want is to get TextField values using ngModel. But I don't know why I'm not getting the values by using user.userName and user.password. Also I try my below code using two way data-binding but it also not working.

Here is my login.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: "Login",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggingIn = true;
  user: User;
  @ViewChild("password") password: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("confirmPassword") confirmPassword: ElementRef;

  constructor(private page: Page, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    this.user = new User();
    // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
  }

  toggleForm() {
    this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
  }

  submit() {
    if (this.isLoggingIn) {
      this.login();
    } else {
      // this.register();
    }
  }

  login() {
    this.alert("login: Username" + this.user.userName)
    this.alert("login: Password" + this.password)
    this.userService.login(this.user);
  }

  focusPassword() {
    this.password.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  focusConfirmPassword() {
    if (!this.isLoggingIn) {
      this.confirmPassword.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  alert(message: string) {
    return alert({
      title: "Hashoo Says",
      okButtonText: "OK",
      message: message
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to create the user in ngOnInit
 `ngOnInit() {
    this.user = new User();
or
this.user={}
    );`

Comment: @lesiano showing undefined.

Comment: also with this.user={}?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted your User class, but it looks like there is something wrong in the User object and its properties. Try to initialise empty values for this object.

```
export class User {
    userName = "";
    password = "";
}
```

Comment: I have one more suggestion - did you import NativeScriptFormsModule in your app or component module?

Answer (score 1):

As @JakubP mentioned I think that you forget to import NativeScriptFormsModule

add in app.module.ts

```
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

...

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptFormsModule, AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `[(ngModel)]` on the template, you will get the field values in the `user` Object when you `submit()` your form.

Just create a `User` in your Component:

```
user: User = {
  userName: '',
  password: '',
  confirmPassword: ''
};

submit() {
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-ngmodel-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your Ref. **NOT IN NATIVESCRIPT** though.

Comment: Strange. Did you check the Sample StackBlitz?

Comment: Yes I have check it. I also work in angular and I know how to write two way data binding logic. but in nativescript this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The `login()` function refers to `this.password` instead of `this.user.password` (which is what the template refers to)

```
login() {
    ...
    this.alert("login: Password" + this.password)
    ...
}
```

I also added a `User` class like JakubP mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52666771/10280206)

```
export class User {
    userName: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Here is a working nativescript playground link (all the code is in HomeComponent) - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=YnvKpn&v=2